# Decode an "Apple Web Archive pasteboard type" item on UIPasteboard

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am copying a webpage and would like to see how the dictionary copied to the UIPasteBoard is composed. I currently log the item on the general pasteboard as follows:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

for (NSDictionary *dict in pasteboard.items) {

    NSLog(@"Dict: %@", dict);
}
```

The output is:

```
Dict: {
    "Apple Web Archive pasteboard type" = <62706c69 73743030 d2010203 0d5f100f 57656253 75627265 736f7572 6365735f 100f5765 624d6169 6e526573 6f757263 65a104d4 05060708 090a0b0c 5e576562 5265736f 75726365 55524c5f 100f5765.............
```

I have tried getting a string for the "Apple Web Archive pasteboard type" key as follows, but with no success:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[dict objectForKey:@""Apple Web Archive pasteboard type""] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"item %@", string);
```

How can I decode the data for this key please?

Answer (score 5):

Apple Web Archive pasteboard type is Plist, for discover keys - open with Plist editor.
Also short piece of code below (getting images info from pasted web page)

```
if ([[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] pasteboardTypes] containsObject:WEB_ARCHIVE]) {
    NSData* archiveData = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] valueForPasteboardType:WEB_ARCHIVE];
    if (archiveData)
    {
        NSError* error = nil;
        id webArchive = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:archiveData options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:NULL error:&error];
        if (error) {
            return;
        }
        NSArray *subItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[webArchive objectForKey:@"WebSubresources"]];
        NSPredicate *iPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"WebResourceMIMEType like 'image*'"];
        NSArray *imagesArray = [subItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:iPredicate];
        for (int i=0; i<[imagesArray count]; i++) {
            NSDictionary *sItem = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            UIImage *sImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[sItem valueForKey:@"WebResourceData"]];
            // handle images
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference, a 3rd party standalone library to access WebArchives on iOS exists:
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/09/decoding-safaris-pasteboard-format/
https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTWebArchive

Answer (score 0):

Check out the WebKit documentation here: [WebArchive Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebArchive_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Keep in mind that this is a 'private' class on iOS.  Sending messages to this object or otherwise interacting with it may be grounds for your app being rejected in review.

Comment: Thanks, but I cant seem to create an instance of the WebDataSourceClass in iOS?

Comment: No, because again, that is a private API on iOS. The UIWebView is far much more opaque than its Mac OS counterpart.

Comment: @Run Loop - What exactly are you trying to get out of the Web Archive?

Comment: I want to determine what keys and values are in the archive dict so that I can recreate it as a normal dict and place on UIPasteBoard

Comment: @Run Loop A WebArchive has an array of WebResource objects.  This will include the textual data in a web page or even images.  It is not an NSDictionary of values.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
NSData *data = (NSData *) [dict objectForKey:[[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: You shouldn't assume that the relevant type will be the first in the `allKeys` array.